# Bootstrap data-toggle not working on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-ui-tooltip

I have a trigger on a bootstrap data toggle that will show a tooltip upon clicking. However, its very inconsistent as it barely works on inital page load but when I refresh the page usually or clear cache it works fine. Is there any way to guarantee that it works in page load.

Ive tried document.ready and window.onload

Script:

```js
(function ($) {
    $(document).ready(function () {
      $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip({trigger: "click" });
    });
 }(jQuery));
 
 window.onload = function (){
  $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip({trigger: "click" });
 };
```

Comment: Does the element with the `data-toggle` attribute exist in the DOM when the page loads, or is it injected via AJAX or some other dynamic logic?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan its injected using react.js

Comment: There's your issue. You have a race condition between that react logic and the document.ready handler. I'd suggest you put this logic in the callback of whatever React code creates the elements.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Great idea thank you! For the answer: I put the javascript code within the componentDidUpdate react method.